# How to use videojs installed with npm with webpack?

Tags: webpack, video.js

- I've installed video.js with npm and now there is a node_modules folder in my laravel project.
- In laravel project i have the file `webpack.mix.js`

I haven't worked with webpack before, i know what it does but i don't know how to implement the video.js package i've installed into my laravel project. The tutorial in documentation is not helpful  https://docs.videojs.com/tutorial-webpack.html

Here is my `webpack.mix.js` file:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

    mix.sourceMaps(!mix.inProduction(), 'source-map');
    mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js/app.js');
    mix.combine([
       'resources/css/app.css',
       'resources/css/banner-white.css',
    ], 'public/css/app.css');
    
    mix.combine([
        'public/js/app.js', 'resources/js/modules/banner'
    ], 'public/js/all.js');
```

On my view `play.blade.php` i have script tags but don't know how to get the `video.js` package i installed.

Comment: I think you just simply import the video as the document says. If laravel has configured to support this file type `eot`, then you don't have to configure anything

Comment: Have you tried running ```npm run dev```? What is your version of nodejs?